# When I try to Increase the quantity of one item, other items in the Cart quantity will also increased

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

am trying to build an e-commerce site, but in cart page am get confused about the logic implementation of quantity increment. Assume I have more that 1 Items in the cart and When I try to Increase the quantity of one item, other items in the Cart will also increased.

am using localstorage to store the cart details, when user click on `ADD TO CART` button.

Please Help me!

**CODE: cartDetails.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../../src/cart-details.css'
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
function CartDetails(props) {
  let ele1;
  let {cno}=props;
  const[ele, setEle]=useState('');
  let[qty, setQty]=useState(1)
  // let [totalPrice.setTotalPrice]=useState()
  let[data,setData]=useState([])

const incrementQty = (index) =>{
    setQty(qty++)
    console.log(index)
}
const decrementQty = (index) =>{
  setQty(qty--)
  console.log(index)
}
```

```
      {data.map((item,index)=>(
      <div className="cart_cont  desktop text-dark" key={index}>
            <div className="innerDiv row m-auto  mt-4  d-flex shadow-lg container">
              {/* <div className="split1"> */}
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center flex-column col-sm d-flex id">
                      <label htmlFor="id" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">ID</label>
                      <p className="m-auto" id="id">{item.id}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex  col-sm  thumbnail">
                      <img src={item.image} className="mt-1 mb-1" alt="image" height="100px" width="80px"/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column col-sm  quantity">
                      <label htmlFor="title" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Title</label>
                      <p className="m-auto" id="title">{item.title}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center col-sm  flex-column unitPrice">
                      <label htmlFor="unitprice" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Unit Price</label>
                      <p className="m-auto unitprice" id="unitprice">Rs. {item.price}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center col-sm  flex-column unitPrice">
                      <label htmlFor="unitprice" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Quantity</label>
                      <div className="btns_mob m-auto d-flex flex-row mx-4">
                              <button className="btn btn-outline-primary mx-1" onClick={()=>decrementQty(index)}>-</button>
                              <button className="btn disabled btn-dark mx-1">{qty}</button>
                              <button className="btn btn-outline-primary mx-1" onClick={()=>incrementQty(index)}>+</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column col-sm  total">
                      <label htmlFor="total" className="text-danger fw-bold m-auto">Total</label>
                      <p className="m-auto total" id="total">N/A</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center  col-sm  rmBtn">
                  <Tooltip title="Delete item">
                      <i className="far fa-2x m-auto fa-trash-alt" id={index} onClick={(btn)=>{
                        btn.preventDefault();
                        console.log('index'+index)
                      let arr= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartDetails'))
                      if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartDetails')).length>1)
                        {
                          ele1 = arr.splice(index-1,1)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          ele1 = arr.splice(index+1,1)
                        } 
                      console.log(ele1)
                      // arr.splice(btn.target.id,1)
                      localStorage.setItem('cartDetails',JSON.stringify(ele1))
                      cno(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartDetails')).length)
                        // setEle(ele1)
                      }}></i></Tooltip>
                  </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
       ))
      }
```

Please help me

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducible example. You have a lot of unnecessary content in your question, and people maybe unlikely to help you.

Comment: The core problem is that you are not using the correct data structure, you only have 1 object, i.e., `qty` to help you track the number of items in your cart. You should instead make the  `data` object more broad to track the number of items individually. You can create a new field, `item.count` that starts with 1 by default ( and if it hits 0 delete it ) and increment `item.count` instead of `qty`.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar so no need to create extra delete button right?

Comment: no, however, you may require to refactor the current logic a little

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar am stucked in logic actually

Answer (score 0):

Because you increase and decrease the state which is not a good practice. And if you want to increase or decrease the only product quantity, then it will be ok. But you can not inc/dec in the cart like that. You have to create two new states for cart items and total quantities. Then you can increase or decrease your cart items and items quantities using these states:

```
const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState([]);
const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);

const toggleCartItemQuantity = (id, value) => {
    foundProduct = cartItem.find((item) => item.id === id);
    index = cartItem.findIndex((product) => product.id === id);
    const newCartItems = cartItem.filter((item) => item.id !== id);

    if (value == 'increase') {
      setCartItem([
        ...newCartItems,
        { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity + 1 },
      ]);
      setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + 1);

    } else if (value == 'decrease') {
      if (foundProduct.quantity > 1) {
        setCartItem([
          ...newCartItems,
          { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity - 1 },
        ]);
        setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities - 1);
      }
    }
  };
```